# Jdbc call to oracle 11.1.0.7.0 db blocked

Tags: oracle, jdbc

The Jdbc call blocks and does not return back .. below is the stack trace

Oracle server = 11.1.0.7
Oracle thin driver used @ client

Would appreciate your help ....

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:240)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:172)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1034)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1010)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:588)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:780)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:855)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1377)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1377)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:670)
```

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver?  Which OS platform?  Does this happen all the time or just intermittently?

Answer (score 2):

there might be few reasons:

1. This thread is locked in DB and waits for other thread commit(or rollback)
2. This can be the firewall issue. Firewall may handle inappropriately  stale connections.
   You can see more information here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4354229

Comment: We have the same issue even though we have setQueryTimeout for the PrepareStatement. However, we are not calling stored procedure, but updating a row. Our jdbc driver version is jdbc-11.1.0.7.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a stored procedure, it is apparently a JDBC THIN driver BUG.

Update your JDBC driver to 11.0.2.2. It's supposed to fix the hang on getNextPacket issue:

```
Oracle JDBC Drivers release 11.2.0.2 Readme.txt
===============================================
Note: this readme is specific to fixes in 11.2.0.2 patch-set; see
the master readme of the 11.2 release at http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/112/Readme.txt

Bug#        Description
=======         ===========================================================================================
2935043     SQLException Invalid conversion error when binding short JDBC type to Oracle number column
5071698     PropertyCheckInterval of zero causes high CPU
6748410     registerOutParameter does not perform well in JDBC Thin
7208615     NUMBER column shows as precision 22 in JDBC
7281435     ORA-30006 during xa_commit cause XAER_RMERR in JDBC
8588311     PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream() does not read all the data from the stream
8592559     JDBC Thin cannot fetch PlsqlIndexByTable with more than 32k items
8617180     ORA-1458 error with large batch sizes using JDBC OCI driver
8832811     Non ASCII characters inserted into US7ASCII DB using JDBC Thin
8834344     Binding date of the Julian calendar throws IllegalArgumentException
8873676     JDBC This throws SqlException while reading invalid characters
8874882     ORA-22922 reusing large string bind for a LOB in JDBC
8889839     XA_RMERR being thrown on the recover(TMNOFLAGS) call from JDBC
8891187     JDBC does not close the connection after a fatal error
8980899     JDBC Thin new property enableDataInLocator for LOB data
8980918     JDBC Thin should use "data in locator" feature to save round-trips for small Lobs
8982104     Add JDBC support for SQLXML
9045206     11.2 JDBC driver returns zero rows with REF CURSOR OUT parameter
9099863     ps.setbytes on BLOB columns in batch does not inherit value to following lines
9105438     ORA-22275 during ps.executeBatch with LOBs
9121586     ORA-22925 getting large LOB via JDBC Thin 11.2
9139227     Wrong error code on JDBC connection failure
9147506     Named parameter in callable statement not working from JDBC
9180882     JDBC Statement.Execute does not handle comments as first elements for INSERT
9197956     JDBC Data Change Notification fails with IllegalArgumentException
9240210     Silent truncation reading 4gb BLOB with JDBC Thin 11.2
9259830     DatabaseChangeNotification fails to clean up
9260568     isValidObjectName() rejects valid object names
9341542     getmetadata().getindexinfo fails with quoted table names (ORA-947)
9341742     setBinaryStream causes dump/ORA-24804 if an unread stream is bound to a DML
9374132     Territory is allowed to be NULL resulting in ORA-12705
9394224     Poor performance for batch PreparedStatement execute with XMLType or objects.
9445675     "No more data" / ORA-3137 using end to end metrics with JDBC Thin
9468517     JDBC OCI and OCI do not behave the same on TAF failover
9491385     Memory not released using registerIndexTableOutParameter in JDBC Thin
9491954     RuntimeException "Assertion botch: negative time" from Timestamp bind
9660015     JDBC Thin hangs by waiting getnextpacket when calling stored procedure
9767715     TIMESTAMPTZ stringvalue truncates leading zeros in decimal part
9786503     Cannot use OS authentication with OracleXADataSource
```

Check out bug #9660015.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the Firewall issue, did you try checking, if the connections were active in DB, or did DB send the 10Byte ping data to this specific connections and it was OK ?
If JDBC able to create the PreparedStatement from Connections it means the Connections were OK from client perspective, however the whats there between DB and Client ? Firewall ? router ? check their settings.